# Workbook name change issue

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my macro code just one issue is every time the dump which we will export the name of that file will get changed every time.

The end number will always change: `"SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11)"`, `"SECONDARY MIS MODULE (12)"`, etc.

```
Sub MySub
    a = 6
    b = 2

    Do While Workbooks("segment.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(b, 1) <> ""
        Z = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Workbooks("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11).xlsx").Worksheets("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11)").Range("B5:K5"), _
            "FRANCHISEE DEVELOPMENT", Workbooks("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11).xlsx").Worksheets("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11)").Range(Cells(a, 2), Cells(a, 11)))

        x = Application.SumIf(Workbooks("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11).xlsx").Worksheets("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11)").Range("B5:K5"), _
            "PRIVATE WEALTH GROUP", Workbooks("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11).xlsx").Worksheets("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (11)").Range(Cells(a, 2), Cells(a, 11)))

        Workbooks("segment.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(b, 13).Value = x + Z
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I understand ? what is the error ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Respected Sir, Actually above mention code i am developing for over daily MIS. The challenge which i am facing with regards to the last no. ie. (11),(12) and so on, which is generated every time when the system generated Dump we have received. is there any way where the code help me out to ignore the last no. and consider the first line i.e. SECONDARY MIS MODULE only.as suggested even if i work out with "For i = 11 to 15"  statement the no ill increase every time and i will have to do editing with the code after every next 5 or 6 days.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to apply this code on multiple workbooks/worksheets. You can simply add workbook name and/or worksheet name as parameters of your method:

```
Sub MySub(wbName As String, wsName As String)
    a = 6
    b = 2

    Do While ' ......
        Z = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets(wsName).Range("B5:K5"), _
            "FRANCHISEE DEVELOPMENT", Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets(wsName).Range(Cells(a, 2), Cells(a, 11)))
        '
        '
        '
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```
For i = 11 To 15
    MySub "SECONDARY MIS MODULE (" & i & ").xlsx", "SECONDARY MIS MODULE (" & i & ").xlsx"
Next
```

---

**Update 1:**

If you don't know the numeric part of the workbook name, you can write a helper function that returns the actual workbook name, something like the following:

```
Function GetWorkbookNameByPartial(pattern As String) As String
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like pattern Then
            GetWorkbookNameByPartial = wb.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim wbName As String
wbName = GetWorkbookNameByPartial("SECONDARY MIS MODULE (*).xlsx")
If Len(wbName) > 0 Then
    MySub wbName, wbName ' Only if worksheet name matches workbook name.
                         ' Otherwise, you will need to change worksheet name.
End If
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Respected Sir, Actually above mention code i am developing for over daily MIS the change which i am facing with regards to the last no which is generated every time when the system genrated Dump we have received.

Comment: @sagar, I edited my answer. Hope that helps you out. On a different note, you need to be aware that almost everyone who read your question struggled to understand your point. Next time, please try to make your question more clear and more straight-forward so you can get help faster instead of getting downvotes. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Sir for your help..next time i will ensure your guidelines as well.

Comment: You're welcome :). If you think that helped you solving your problem, you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sir, when I am using your given code I am receiving Compile error: Sub or Function not defined.please help